# django form custom attrs widget imagefield

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-widget

I have a model **Prova**:

```
class Prova(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    codice=  models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='stati/uploads/', blank=True)
```

and this is the **form**:

```
class ProvaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Prova
        fields = ('codice','foto',)
        widgets = {
            'codice': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':1, 'cols':15,
                                            'autofocus':'autofocus',
            }),
            'foto': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'type': 'camera'}),

            }
```

the customization of the **codice** field is working, but not the **foto**.
I want to change the type of html input from 'file' to specific image from 'camera'.

Tried also ImageField and

```
 'foto': forms.FileInput(attrs={'capture': 'camera'}),
```

What am I missing to get it like the pure html:

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: So, the rendered `<input>` will not have a button to choose file for the image, right? Note, that `type=camera` is not a registered name for `input`s and browsers cannot parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`camera` **is not** valid HTML for the value of the `type` attribute of an `input` element.

If you do change it to `<input type="camera" name="a-name-here" value="some-value">`, then Chrome and FF will render it as a text input, while your `ProvaForm` expects a file (an `ImageField`), resulting in a failed validation. Of course you can override the validation part, by writting you own one, but what's the point of using an `ImageField` from the start if instead this field is going to be rendered as a text?

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types) for the possible values of the `type` attribute of an `input` element.